# JSON not working with OnChange event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I originally coded this piece to bring back a single data point.  I realized I needed more fields returned with an onchange event (drop down select) and changed it to use JSON.  It is not returning any data.  The drop down is built dynamically through PHP when the page is first loaded.  I'm new to this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Dropdown Code:

```
<p id="dropdown"   style="DISPLAY: none" >
        <?php
            $query = "call test.spsMSTR_AllCatListBuild";
            $stmt = $conn->query( $query );

            $dropdown = "<select id='catlist' name='catlist' onchange='getval(this);'>";
                $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value= 'NA'>Select Category</option>";
                foreach ($stmt as $row) {
                  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['ID']}'>{$row['RPT_NAME']}</option>";
                }

                $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
                echo $dropdown;
                $conn = null;
        ?>
    </p>
```

Ajax/JSON code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#catlist").change(function(){
            var vid = document.getElementById("catlist").value;

            $.getjson("ajax.php",
            {catid:vid},
            function(result){
                alert(result); }
                .error(function(xhr) {
                    alert(xhr)
                })
                ; )
        })})

  </script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php include('./DBConfig.php'); ?>
<?php

    $vid = $_GET["catid"];
    $query =  "SELECT RPT_NAME, ACTIVE FROM test.MSTR_REPORT_MASTER WHERE ID = $vid" ;
    $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
    //$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: are there any errors in your browser console? Also, I'm not really sure why you're mixing in normal Javascript if you are using jquery.

Comment: First off, it's `getJSON` and change `document.getElementById("catlist").value` to `$(this).val()` and remove `onchange='getval(this);` from your `select`

Comment: Exactly what I was gonna write -__-

Comment: I've gotten no errors in the browser, at least none I can see.  Like I said, I'm new to this.  What do you mean by mixing in normal Javascript if using JQuery?

Comment: OP, just open your console (F12). I's surely yelling errors like `getjson is undefined`.

Comment: Check your browser console as @JeremyThille and I have suggested by pressing F12 then look for a tab called console. Any js errors will be listed there.....What I mean by mixing jquery with normal javascript is you are getting your value with normal javascript `document.getElementById` but then using jquery shorthand for your ajax call

Comment: Try changing: `var vid = document.getElementById("catlist").value;` to: `var vid = $('#catlist').val();`

Comment: Opened up the console and this is what I'm seeing: Uncaught ReferenceError: getval is not defined
AdminEdit.php:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: getval is not definedAdminEdit.php:42 onchange        This points to this line: <select id='catlist' name='catlist' onchange='getval(this);'>

Comment: Also, I went ahead and changed it to getJSON and updated how the var definition as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have corrected your errors and you should have the below for it to work with no errors, unless there is something else that is causing errors.

```
<select id='catlist' name='catlist'>
    <option value='NA'>Select Category</option>
    <option value='id1'>val1</option>
    <option value='id2'>val2</option>
    <option value='id3'>val3</option>
</select>

$(function(){
    $("#catlist").change(function() {
        var sVal = $(this).val();
        if (sVal !== "NA") { // I am assuming you don't want to make an ajax call when the value is 'NA'!
            $.getJSON("ajax.php", {catid: $(this).val()}, function(result) {
                alert(result); 
            });
            //by the way $(this).val() = id1|id2|id3
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes!!! This worked! Thank you so much.  I don't have enough reputation yet, but when I do, I will upvote this.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you format your code, you can see your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#catlist").change(function() {
    var vid = document.getElementById("catlist").value;

    $.getjson("ajax.php", {
        catid: vid
      },
      function(result) {
        alert(result);
      }
      .error(function(xhr) {   //<-- error inside getJSON
        alert(xhr)
      });)                     //<-- a random )
  })
})
```

and

You have an inline event `onchange='getval(this);'` but you do not have a function `getval` listed.