# Javascript retrieve data from mysql database using switch case in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I will try to describe it simpler as i can.

I have this html:

```
<fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
    <select name="localita" id="localita" onchange="cambia()">
        <option value="Tutti">Tutti</option>
        <option value="Location 1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="Location 2">Location 2</option>
        <option value="Location 3">Location 3</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Connected to this javascript:

```
<script>
    function cambia() {
        $.post("switch_localita.php", {
            localita : $("#localita").val()
        }).done(function(data) {
        });
    }
</script>
```

which is connected to this php file:

```
$localita = $_POST['localita'];
switch ($localita) {
    case "Location 1" :
        $sql = "my query";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Query error: " . mysqli_error());
        $records = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
        echo json_encode($records);
        break;
    case "Location 2" :
        //my stuff
        break;
    case "Location 3" :
        //my stuff
        break;
    default :
    //mystuff
}
```

And finally i retrieve with this ajax / json:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax('switch_localita.php', {
        dataType : "json",
        jsonp : "jsoncallback",
        method : 'post',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        success : function(data, status) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                //my stuff
            });
        },
        error : function(xhr, d, s) {
            $('#output').empty().html(s);
        }
    });
</script>
```

The question is: how do i make all this working?
i need that, once the select content changes (another voice is selected), the form is submitted and retrieves the correct query from the switch case stored in the php file. Also i need that a standard query is displayed when opened the page (so, if you open the page, you don't have already selected a voice, but a query loads anyway.).

Thank you

Comment: You don't need 2 ajax requests for this. `$.post` is simply a shorthand method `$.ajax` and does the same thing. Seem to be over complicating things here. As for page load...simply check if $_POST is empty. your whole flow process is still a bit vague though

Comment: my app reads javascript only. So i have to send data via javascript, elaborate with php, return a json encoded value that is elaborated via ajax and printed as html. lol

Comment: That sounds like a logic/ process flow problem then to need to make a second request immediately after making first request. Nothing has changed so no reason server can't process both at same time.

Comment: so...can you give me a solution? because my actual code always retrieves me the condition where $_POST['localita'] is not set (so the default query is printed).

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is actually sent and received. Also no `jsonp` involved here. Make sure use `'json` for datatype and add some ajax error handling also

Comment: datatype is set to json, yes. ajax does not give me error since it reads from php that the variable $_POST is not set and reads the default query. It's ok. The problem is: does the cambia() methos send the $_POST variable to php file? If yes, why ajax does not read it but instead always reads the query outsite the switch/case construct? mh...

Comment: What is actually send in the browser request? Inspect that for starters. You can see it right in browser dev tools network

Comment: how do i check it?

Comment: Go to network tab of browser dev tools (F12) and open that request

Comment: ok i see switch_localita.php returns the correct json_encoded "string": So, now?

Comment: Now what? We don't know what you are doing with the response. There is no code shown for that. Also no idea what is wrong

Comment: could you post a working code based on mine?

Comment: @charlietfl please!

Comment: Please what? Have no idea what you want to do with the response. There isn't any html structure or sample data shown in question.

Answer (score 1):

heres an updated one with json encode and $get ajax.

this is your html

```
<fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
    <select name="localita" id="localita"">
        <option value="Tutti">Tutti</option>
        <option value="Location 1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="Location 2">Location 2</option>
        <option value="Location 3">Location 3</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
<div class="the-return"></div>
```

i add a div for the data to be printed.

this is your ajax

```
$(function(){
    $("#localita").change(function() {
        var sVal = $(this).val();
        if (sVal !== "NA") { // I am assuming you don't want to make an ajax call when the value is 'NA'!
            $.getJSON("response.php", {localita: $(this).val()}, function(result) {
                $(".the-return").html(
                  "Your Location : " + result //this is where u decide how ur data going to be printed
                );
                alert(result); 
            });
            //by the way $(this).val() = id1|id2|id3
        }
    });
})
```

this is your php.

```
<?php

$localita = $_GET['localita'];
switch ($localita) {
    case "Location 1" :
         $sql = "my query";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Query error: " . mysqli_error());
        $records = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
        echo json_encode($records);
        break;
    case "Location 2" :
        //my stuff
        break;
    case "Location 3" :
        //my stuff
        break;
    default :
    //mystuff
}

?>
```

this code is based on an answer on this question = [JSON not working with OnChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214977/json-not-working-with-onchange-event)

hope it works for you.

Comment: i have to get results in javascript too. I can't use <?php ?> since my app (i'm working on jquery mobile) reads javascript only. So i have to return back a json encoded result and get it via ajax.

Comment: it is sent through javascript. the php is processed on back-end and javascript will post the result on `success : function (html)`

Comment: in your code you have $localita instead of $data in the php switch case. Is it correct?

Comment: @Tony33 u fix it? see my edits if you still have trouble with it